# Slave I/O: error connecting to master

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ssl, nginx, database-replication

I'm following this tutorial for [Master-slave-replication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql)
for my database replication and this working fine for test servers in which both servers have not ssl installed. But when I trying to do the same with my production server where only master has ssl installed not slave server, I'm getting this error `Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'server-ipaddress:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400, Error_code: 2003`. Is this problem of ssl connection or something else.

Also when setting up mysql configuration on master server after taking dump file of database and unlocking tables my mysql server shut down with my website showing this error `error establishing database connection` after restarting mysql my website working fine again.

My master server is running on nginx server with wordpress installed and I have also checked that 3306 is listening on my master server. 
Why my slave unable to connect to my master server, any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use command below to check the ip address mysql server is listening

```
netstat -nlt | grep 3306

sample result:

tcp 0  0  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306  0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN
```

If the result showing same result like me then add a replication master user to access the server database.

If netfilter firewall is enabled `(sudo ufw enable)` on mysql server machine, do the following to open port 3306 for remote access:

```
sudo ufw allow 3306
```

check status again :

```
sudo ufw status
```

You will see your tcp port for 3306 is open for connection from anywhere. Now you try to connect from slave server you will get the result.

Answer (score 1):

i solved like this:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -s ipmaster --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'Ahmad@192.168.1.10:3306' - retry-time: 60  maximum-retries: 86400  message: Host 'Sardar' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).